# Issues with Fortran77 code - Multiline text

Tags: syntax, fortran, fortran77

I am building an executable version of a program using Visual Studio 2019 and Intel Parallel Studio XE 2020. The program requires a Fortran static library to be built. The program allows for user macros to be included in the build. I am trying to include a user macro so that a the program can generate a TECPLOT output. The user macro for the TECPLOT output was created by someone else.

When I include the user macro I am getting the following errors:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Compilation Aborted (code 1)        C:\Users\ankit\Desktop\feapwtecplot\ver85\compile\umacr1.f  1   
Error       error #5078: Unrecognized token '\' skipped     C:\Users\ankit\Desktop\feapwtecplot\ver85\compile\umacr1.f  102 
Error       error #5082: Syntax error, found END-OF-STATEMENT when expecting one of: ( <IDENTIFIER> <CHAR_CON_KIND_PARAM> <CHAR_NAM_KIND_PARAM> <CHARACTER_CONSTANT> <INTEGER_CONSTANT> ...     C:\Users\ankit\Desktop\feapwtecplot\ver85\compile\umacr1.f  102 
Error       error #5082: Syntax error, found ',' when expecting one of: <END-OF-STATEMENT> ;        C:\Users\ankit\Desktop\feapwtecplot\ver85\compile\umacr1.f  102 
Error       error #5078: Unrecognized token '\' skipped     C:\Users\ankit\Desktop\feapwtecplot\ver85\compile\umacr1.f  102 
Error       error #5082: Syntax error, found ''' when expecting one of: ) ( , : <END-OF-STATEMENT> ; % [ . = / =>       C:\Users\ankit\Desktop\feapwtecplot\ver85\compile\umacr1.f  102 
Error       error #5078: Unrecognized token '\' skipped     C:\Users\ankit\Desktop\feapwtecplot\ver85\compile\umacr1.f  102 
Error       error #5078: Unrecognized token '\' skipped     C:\Users\ankit\Desktop\feapwtecplot\ver85\compile\umacr1.f  102 
Error       error #5078: Unrecognized token '\' skipped     C:\Users\ankit\Desktop\feapwtecplot\ver85\compile\umacr1.f  102 
Error       error #5078: Unrecognized token '\' skipped     C:\Users\ankit\Desktop\feapwtecplot\ver85\compile\umacr1.f  103 
Error       error #5078: Unrecognized token '\' skipped     C:\Users\ankit\Desktop\feapwtecplot\ver85\compile\umacr1.f  103 
Error       error #5078: Unrecognized token '\' skipped     C:\Users\ankit\Desktop\feapwtecplot\ver85\compile\umacr1.f  103 
Error       error #5082: Syntax error, found END-OF-STATEMENT when expecting one of: ( <IDENTIFIER> <CHAR_CON_KIND_PARAM> <CHAR_NAM_KIND_PARAM> <CHARACTER_CONSTANT> <INTEGER_CONSTANT> ...     C:\Users\ankit\Desktop\feapwtecplot\ver85\compile\umacr1.f  103 
Error       error #5078: Unrecognized token '\' skipped     C:\Users\ankit\Desktop\feapwtecplot\ver85\compile\umacr1.f  103 
Error       error #5078: Unrecognized token '\' skipped     C:\Users\ankit\Desktop\feapwtecplot\ver85\compile\umacr1.f  103 
Error       error #5078: Unrecognized token '\' skipped     C:\Users\ankit\Desktop\feapwtecplot\ver85\compile\umacr1.f  103 
Error       error #5078: Unrecognized token '\' skipped     C:\Users\ankit\Desktop\feapwtecplot\ver85\compile\umacr1.f  103 
Error       error #5078: Unrecognized token '\' skipped     C:\Users\ankit\Desktop\feapwtecplot\ver85\compile\umacr1.f  103 
Error       error #5082: Syntax error, found '&' when expecting one of: <LABEL> <END-OF-STATEMENT> ; <IDENTIFIER> TYPE MODULE ELEMENTAL IMPURE NON_RECURSIVE ...        C:\Users\ankit\Desktop\feapwtecplot\ver85\compile\umacr1.f  103 
Error       error #5078: Unrecognized token '\' skipped     C:\Users\ankit\Desktop\feapwtecplot\ver85\compile\umacr1.f  104 
Error       error #5082: Syntax error, found '&' when expecting one of: <LABEL> <END-OF-STATEMENT> ; <IDENTIFIER> TYPE MODULE ELEMENTAL IMPURE NON_RECURSIVE ...        C:\Users\ankit\Desktop\feapwtecplot\ver85\compile\umacr1.f  104 
Error       error #5120: Unterminated character constant        C:\Users\ankit\Desktop\feapwtecplot\ver85\compile\umacr1.f  104 
Error       error #5082: Syntax error, found '&' when expecting one of: <LABEL> <END-OF-STATEMENT> ; <IDENTIFIER> TYPE MODULE ELEMENTAL IMPURE NON_RECURSIVE ...        C:\Users\ankit\Desktop\feapwtecplot\ver85\compile\umacr1.f  115 
Error       error #5082: Syntax error, found END-OF-STATEMENT when expecting one of: ( <IDENTIFIER> <CHAR_CON_KIND_PARAM> <CHAR_NAM_KIND_PARAM> <CHARACTER_CONSTANT> <INTEGER_CONSTANT> ...     C:\Users\ankit\Desktop\feapwtecplot\ver85\compile\umacr1.f  115 
Error       error #5082: Syntax error, found '&' when expecting one of: <LABEL> <END-OF-STATEMENT> ; <IDENTIFIER> TYPE MODULE ELEMENTAL IMPURE NON_RECURSIVE ...        C:\Users\ankit\Desktop\feapwtecplot\ver85\compile\umacr1.f  116 
Error       error #5082: Syntax error, found END-OF-STATEMENT when expecting one of: ( <IDENTIFIER> <CHAR_CON_KIND_PARAM> <CHAR_NAM_KIND_PARAM> <CHARACTER_CONSTANT> <INTEGER_CONSTANT> ...     C:\Users\ankit\Desktop\feapwtecplot\ver85\compile\umacr1.f  116 
Error       error #5082: Syntax error, found '&' when expecting one of: <LABEL> <END-OF-STATEMENT> ; <IDENTIFIER> TYPE MODULE ELEMENTAL IMPURE NON_RECURSIVE ...        C:\Users\ankit\Desktop\feapwtecplot\ver85\compile\umacr1.f  117 
Error       error #5082: Syntax error, found END-OF-STATEMENT when expecting one of: ( <IDENTIFIER> <CHAR_CON_KIND_PARAM> <CHAR_NAM_KIND_PARAM> <CHARACTER_CONSTANT> <INTEGER_CONSTANT> ...     C:\Users\ankit\Desktop\feapwtecplot\ver85\compile\umacr1.f  117 
Error       error #5082: Syntax error, found END-OF-STATEMENT when expecting one of: ( <IDENTIFIER> <CHAR_CON_KIND_PARAM> <CHAR_NAM_KIND_PARAM> <CHARACTER_CONSTANT> <INTEGER_CONSTANT> ...     C:\Users\ankit\Desktop\feapwtecplot\ver85\compile\umacr1.f  118 
Error       error #5082: Syntax error, found '&' when expecting one of: <LABEL> <END-OF-STATEMENT> ; <IDENTIFIER> TYPE MODULE ELEMENTAL IMPURE NON_RECURSIVE ...        C:\Users\ankit\Desktop\feapwtecplot\ver85\compile\umacr1.f  118 
Error       error #5082: Syntax error, found '&' when expecting one of: <LABEL> <END-OF-STATEMENT> ; <IDENTIFIER> TYPE MODULE ELEMENTAL IMPURE NON_RECURSIVE ...        C:\Users\ankit\Desktop\feapwtecplot\ver85\compile\umacr1.f  119
```

I believe the errors are syntax based, specifically line 102, where I am writing multiline text. The Usermacro is below:

```
      subroutine umacr1(lct,ctl)
c-----[--.----+----.----+----.-----------------------------------------]
      implicit  none

      include  'iofile.h'
      include  'ioincl.h'     
      include  'counts.h'
      include  'umac1.h'
      include  'pointer.h'
      include  'comblk.h'     
      include  'cdata.h'
      include  'sdata.h'      
      include  'comfil.h'
c     include  'pfeapb.h'

      logical   pcomp
      integer   j
      character lct*15,dump*17
      real*8    ctl(3)

      save

c     Set command word

      if(pcomp(uct,'mac1',4)) then      ! Usual form
        uct = 'tecp'                    ! Specify 'name'
      elseif(urest.eq.1) then           ! Read  restart data

      elseif(urest.eq.2) then           ! Write restart data

      elseif(pcomp(lct,'init',4)) then  ! open output unit; incl. counter

c     Try to open file for later use (filename based on input file)
       write(dump,1999) nstep
cc     Identify parition in the parallel case
c       if(pfeap_on) then
c        dump = fplt(LEN_TRIM(fplt)-4:LEN_TRIM(fplt)) // dump
c       endif   
       dump = 'tecout' // dump
       open(unit=99, file=dump)
       write(*,*) 'Saving TECPLOT data to ',dump

      elseif(pcomp(lct,'close',4)) then ! close output unit
       close(unit=99)

      elseif(pcomp(lct,'write',4)) then ! output postprocessing data

c     Write nodal postprocessing data

c     2D Data
       if(ndm.eq.2) then
          write(99,*) 'TITLE=\"FEM DATA, FEAP->TECPLOT\"'
          write(99,*) 'VARIABLES=\"X\",\"Y\",\"DX\",\"DY\",\"UX\",
    &\"UY\",\"FX\",\"FY\",\"1-PR\",\"2-PR\",\"3-PR\",\"I-1\",\"J-2\",
    &\"J-3\"'

          write(99,2001) numnp,numel
          if(nen.eq.4) then
            write(99,*) 'DATAPACKING=POINT, ZONETYPE=FEQUADRILATERAL'
          elseif(nen.eq.3) then
            write(99,*) 'DATAPACKING=POINT, ZONETYPE=FETRIANGLE'
          endif

          do j=0,numnp-1
               write(99,2011)
    &          hr(np(43)+j*ndm),hr(np(43)+j*ndm+1),  ! nodal coor X 43
    &          hr(np(40)+j*ndf),hp(np(40)+j*ndf+1),  ! nodal disp U 40
    &          hr(np(43)+j*ndm),hr(np(40)+j*ndf),    ! deformed nodal pos.
    &          hr(np(43)+j*ndm+1),hr(np(40)+j*ndf+1),
    &          hr(np(27)+j*ndm),hr(np(27)+j*ndm+1),  ! forces, disp F 27
    &          hr(np(57)+numnp*1+j),                 ! principal stress 1
    &          hr(np(57)+numnp*2+j),                 ! principal stress 2
    &          hr(np(57)+numnp*3+j),                 ! principal stress 3
    &          hr(np(57)+numnp*4+j),                 ! I 1
    &          hr(np(57)+numnp*5+j),                 ! J 2
    &          hr(np(57)+numnp*6+j)                  ! J 3 (v. Mises-Stress)
          end do
c         'Array 33 IX: Element Connections'
          if(nen.eq.4) then      !quadrilateral
            do j=0,numel-1
                 write(99,2003) mr(np(33)+j*nen1),mr(np(33)+j*nen1+1),
    &                           mr(np(33)+j*nen1+2)
            end do
          endif !nen

c      3D Data
       elseif((ndm.eq.3).and.(ndf.eq.3)) then  ! classic continuum elem.

          write(99,*) 'TITLE=\"FEM DATA, FEAP->TECPLOT\"'
          write(99,*) 'VARIABLES=\"X\",\"Y\",\"DX\",\"DY\",\"UX\",
    &\"UY\",\"FX\",\"FY\",\"1-PR\",\"2-PR\",\"3-PR\",\"I-1\",\"J-2\",
    &\"J-3\"'

          write(99,2001) numnp,numel
          if(nen.eq.8 .or. nen.eq.27 .or. nen.eq.20) then
            write(99,*) 'DATAPACKING=POINT, ZONETYPE=FEBRICK'
          elseif(nen.eq.4 .or. nen.eq.10 .or. nen.eq.11) then
            write(99,*) 'DATAPACKING=POINT, ZONETYPE=FETETRAHEDRON'
          endif 

          do j=0,numnp-1
               write(99,2013)
    &          hr(np(43)+j*ndm),hr(np(43)+j*ndm+1),hr(np(43)+j*ndm+2),
    &          hr(np(40)+j*ndf),hp(np(40)+j*ndf+1),hp(np(40)+j*ndf+2),
    &          hr(np(43)+j*ndm),hr(np(40)+j*ndf),    ! deformed nodal pos.
    &          hr(np(43)+j*ndm+1),hr(np(40)+j*ndf+1),
    &          hr(np(43)+j*ndm+2),hr(np(40)+j*ndf+2),   
    &          hr(np(27)+j*ndf),hr(np(27)+j*ndf+1),hr(np(27)+j*ndf+2),
    &          hr(np(57)+numnp*1+j),                 ! principal stress 1
    &          hr(np(57)+numnp*2+j),                 ! principal stress 2
    &          hr(np(57)+numnp*3+j),                 ! principal stress 3
    &          hr(np(57)+numnp*4+j),                 ! I 1
    &          hr(np(57)+numnp*5+j),                 ! J 2
    &          hr(np(57)+numnp*6+j)                  ! J 3 (v. Mises-Stress)
          end do
c         'Array 33 IX: Element Connections'
          if(nen.eq.8 .or. nen.eq.27 .or. nen.eq.20) then        !hexahedral
            do j=0,numel-1
                 write(99,2014) 
    &            mr(np(33)+j*nen1),mr(np(33)+j*nen1+1),
    &            mr(np(33)+j*nen1+2),mr(np(33)+j*nen1+3),
    &            mr(np(33)+j*nen1+4),mr(np(33)+j*nen1+5),
    &            mr(np(33)+j*nen1+6),mr(np(33)+j*nen1+7)
            end do
          elseif(nen.eq.4 .or. nen.eq.10 .or. nen.eq.11) then    !tetrahedral
            do j=0,numel-1
    &            mr(np(33)+j*nen1),mr(np(33)+j*nen1+1),
    &            mr(np(33)+j*nen1+2),mr(np(33)+j*nen1+3)
            end do
          endif

c      
       elseif((ndm.eq.3).and.(ndf.eq.6)) then  ! micropolar continuum elem.     

          write(99,*) 'TITLE=\"FEM DATA, FEAP->TECPLOT\"'
          write(99,*) 'VARIABLES=\"X\",\"Y\",\"DX\",\"DY\",\"DZ\",
    &\"RX\",\"RY\",\"RZ\",
    &\"FX\",\"FY\",\"FZ\",
    &\"MX\",\"MY\",\"MZ\",
    &\"sig11\",\"sig12\",\"sig13\",
    &\"sig21\",\"sig22\",\"sig23\", 
    &\"sig31\",\"sig32\",\"sig33\", 
    &\"sigc11\",\"sigc12\",\"sigc13\",
    &\"sigc21\",\"sigc22\",\"sigc23\",  
    &\"sigc31\",\"sigc32\",\"sigc33\"'
          write(99,2001) numnp,numel
          if(nen.eq.8 .or. nen.eq.27 .or. nen.eq.20) then
            write(99,*) 'DATAPACKING=POINT, ZONETYPE=FEBRICK'
          elseif(nen.eq.4 .or. nen.eq.10 .or. nen.eq.11) then
            write(99,*) 'DATAPACKING=POINT, ZONETYPE=FETETRAHEDRON'
          endif 

          do j=0,numnp-1
               write(99,2016)
    &          hr(np(43)+j*ndm),hr(np(43)+j*ndm+1),hr(np(43)+j*ndm+2),
    &          hr(np(40)+j*ndf),hp(np(40)+j*ndf+1),hp(np(40)+j*ndf+2),
    &          hr(np(40)+j*ndf+3),hp(np(40)+j*ndf+4),hp(np(40)+j*ndf+5),
    &          hr(np(27)+j*ndf),hr(np(27)+j*ndf+1),hr(np(27)+j*ndf+2),
    &          hr(np(27)+j*ndf+3),hr(np(27)+j*ndf+4),hr(np(27)+j*ndf+4),
    &          hr(np(58)+numnp*1+j),hr(np(58)+numnp*2+j),
    &          hr(np(58)+numnp*3+j),hr(np(58)+numnp*4+j),
    &          hr(np(58)+numnp*5+j),hr(np(58)+numnp*6+j),
    &          hr(np(58)+numnp*7+j),hr(np(58)+numnp*8+j),
    &          hr(np(58)+numnp*9+j),
    &          hr(np(58)+numnp*10+j),hr(np(58)+numnp*11+j),
    &          hr(np(58)+numnp*12+j),hr(np(58)+numnp*13+j),
    &          hr(np(58)+numnp*14+j),hr(np(58)+numnp*15+j),
    &          hr(np(58)+numnp*16+j),hr(np(58)+numnp*17+j),
    &          hr(np(58)+numnp*18+j)
          end do
c         'Array 33 IX: Element Connections'
          if(nen.eq.8 .or. nen.eq.27 .or. nen.eq.20) then        !hexahedral
            do j=0,numel-1
                 write(99,2014) 
    &            mr(np(33)+j*nen1),mr(np(33)+j*nen1+1),
    &            mr(np(33)+j*nen1+2),mr(np(33)+j*nen1+3),
    &            mr(np(33)+j*nen1+4),mr(np(33)+j*nen1+5),
    &            mr(np(33)+j*nen1+6),mr(np(33)+j*nen1+7)
            end do
          elseif(nen.eq.4 .or. nen.eq.10 .or. nen.eq.11) then    !tetrahedral
            do j=0,numel-1
    &            mr(np(33)+j*nen1),mr(np(33)+j*nen1+1),
    &            mr(np(33)+j*nen1+2),mr(np(33)+j*nen1+3)
            end do
          endif

       endif
      endif

c     Modified filename format
1999  format('_',I4.4,'.dat')
2001  format('ZONE N=',I6,' E=',I6)
c     2D formats
2002  format(14(F16.8,4X))
2003  format(4(I6,4X))
2004  format(3(I6,4X))
c     3D formats
2011  format(16(F16.8,4X))
2012  format(18(F16.8,4X))
2013  format(22(F16.8,4X))
c
2014  format(8(I6,4X))
2015  format(4(I6,4X))
2016  format(33(F16.8,4X))

      end
```

---

Update:
I followed @steve and @francescalus however I am still getting the following errors:

```
Error       error #5082: Syntax error, found '&' when expecting one of: <LABEL> <END-OF-STATEMENT> ; <IDENTIFIER> TYPE MODULE ELEMENTAL IMPURE NON_RECURSIVE ...        C:\Users\ankit\Desktop\feapwtecplot\ver85\compile\umacr1.f  115 
Error       error #5082: Syntax error, found END-OF-STATEMENT when expecting one of: ( <IDENTIFIER> <CHAR_CON_KIND_PARAM> <CHAR_NAM_KIND_PARAM> <CHARACTER_CONSTANT> <INTEGER_CONSTANT> ...     C:\Users\ankit\Desktop\feapwtecplot\ver85\compile\umacr1.f  115 
Error       error #5082: Syntax error, found '&' when expecting one of: <LABEL> <END-OF-STATEMENT> ; <IDENTIFIER> TYPE MODULE ELEMENTAL IMPURE NON_RECURSIVE ...        C:\Users\ankit\Desktop\feapwtecplot\ver85\compile\umacr1.f  116 
Error       error #5082: Syntax error, found END-OF-STATEMENT when expecting one of: ( <IDENTIFIER> <CHAR_CON_KIND_PARAM> <CHAR_NAM_KIND_PARAM> <CHARACTER_CONSTANT> <INTEGER_CONSTANT> ...     C:\Users\ankit\Desktop\feapwtecplot\ver85\compile\umacr1.f  116 
Error       error #5082: Syntax error, found '&' when expecting one of: <LABEL> <END-OF-STATEMENT> ; <IDENTIFIER> TYPE MODULE ELEMENTAL IMPURE NON_RECURSIVE ...        C:\Users\ankit\Desktop\feapwtecplot\ver85\compile\umacr1.f  117 
Error       error #5082: Syntax error, found END-OF-STATEMENT when expecting one of: ( <IDENTIFIER> <CHAR_CON_KIND_PARAM> <CHAR_NAM_KIND_PARAM> <CHARACTER_CONSTANT> <INTEGER_CONSTANT> ...     C:\Users\ankit\Desktop\feapwtecplot\ver85\compile\umacr1.f  117 
Error       error #5082: Syntax error, found END-OF-STATEMENT when expecting one of: ( <IDENTIFIER> <CHAR_CON_KIND_PARAM> <CHAR_NAM_KIND_PARAM> <CHARACTER_CONSTANT> <INTEGER_CONSTANT> ...     C:\Users\ankit\Desktop\feapwtecplot\ver85\compile\umacr1.f  118 
Error       error #5082: Syntax error, found '&' when expecting one of: <LABEL> <END-OF-STATEMENT> ; <IDENTIFIER> TYPE MODULE ELEMENTAL IMPURE NON_RECURSIVE ...        C:\Users\ankit\Desktop\feapwtecplot\ver85\compile\umacr1.f  118 
Error       error #5082: Syntax error, found '&' when expecting one of: <LABEL> <END-OF-STATEMENT> ; <IDENTIFIER> TYPE MODULE ELEMENTAL IMPURE NON_RECURSIVE ...        C:\Users\ankit\Desktop\feapwtecplot\ver85\compile\umacr1.f  119
```

These errors reference the following lines:

```
          do j=0,numnp-1
               write(99,2011)
     &          hr(np(43)+j*ndm),hr(np(43)+j*ndm+1),  ! nodal coor X 43
     &          hr(np(40)+j*ndf),hp(np(40)+j*ndf+1),  ! nodal disp U 40
     &          hr(np(43)+j*ndm),hr(np(40)+j*ndf),    ! deformed nodal pos.
     &          hr(np(43)+j*ndm+1),hr(np(40)+j*ndf+1),
     &          hr(np(27)+j*ndm),hr(np(27)+j*ndm+1),  ! forces, disp F 27
     &          hr(np(57)+numnp*1+j),                 ! principal stress 1
     &          hr(np(57)+numnp*2+j),                 ! principal stress 2
     &          hr(np(57)+numnp*3+j),                 ! principal stress 3
     &          hr(np(57)+numnp*4+j),                 ! I 1
     &          hr(np(57)+numnp*5+j),                 ! J 2
     &          hr(np(57)+numnp*6+j)                  ! J 3 (v. Mises-Stress)
          end do
```

I have ensured that the ampersand is in the correct column.

TIA

Comment: Before anyone can answer your question, you need to explain what you're trying to accomplish.  Fortran does not have "user macro"s.

Comment: We do need much more detail to fix your problem, paying particular attention to the formatting of your code in the code box above (make sure the columns match up in the right columns).  For example: what is the _exact_ message from the compiler?  is the code treated as fixed- or free-form source?

Comment: That said, `\"` is not a correct "escaping" to be used in Fortran.  You should be happy with `"` rather than `\"`.  If this line is automatically generated by some other tool, then we'll need to see that tool to comment/correct it.

Comment: @steve: I have updated my post and hopefully it is easier to understand now. Thank you!

Comment: @francescalus:  I have updated my post and hopefully it is easier to understand now. Thank you!

Comment: Looks like fixed-form code.  The continuation character (your ampersand) needs to be in column 6.  In addition, lines should not exceed 72 characters.  As mentioned by @francescalus, you likely do not need the backslash.

Comment: What is the column number of the `&` in the given code snippet? are there any `<TAB>` characters in your file (there shouldn't be any).

Comment: @albert there are no <tab. characters and all the & are in column 6.

Comment: It seems like the compiler is treating the source as free-format, which expects a continuation character of `&` at the end of the line (but before trailing comments). You may need to change the file extension or explicitly tell the compiler to treat it as fixed-format. However, a quick workaround is to add a `&` in column 73 which is beyond the end of fixed-form source lines (anything past column 72 is ignored; long story involving 80-column punched cards in 1956). This makes the source interpretable either as fixed or free format.

Comment: Please rename your source file `umacr1.f` into `umacr1.for` and check, if it compiles now? Intel Fortran interprets the `.for` extension as fixed format.